# Can't DROP TABLE unknown table (ERROR 1051)

Tags: mysql

I want to remove a table, but when I execute DROP TABLE catalog_product_flat_1 I get:

```
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'catalog_product_flat_1'
```

When I run `DROP VIEW catalog_product_flat_1` I get:

```
#1347 - 'magento.catalog_product_flat_1' is not VIEW
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What *is* that thing then? You need to find out. `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is a place to start.

Comment: @tadman Thanks I get all results NULL with comment: `Incorrect information in file: './magento/catalog_product_flat_1.frm'`

Comment: Sounds like your database may be corrupted. Try using `REPAIR`. And [dba.se] is the place to ask questions about configuring and managing the DB, [so] is for programming questions.